# Hardy's inequality proof using Doob's inquality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider a probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1],\lambda),p>1$ and $f \in L^p(]0,\infty[).$

We want to prove Hardy's inequality using martingale theory and Doob's maximal inequalities.
Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $]k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}],k=0,...,2^n-1.$

I managed to find, for an integrable function $h,$ $E[h|\mathcal{F}_n](x): E[h|\mathcal{F}_n]=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\int_{k2^{-n}}^{(k+1)2^{-n}}h(y)dy1_{]k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]}(x),x \in [0,1].$

It is sufficient to prove $$\left(\int_0^1\left|\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(y)dy\right|^pdx\right)^{1/p} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \left(\int_0^1\left|f(x)\right|^p dx\right)^{1/p},$$ since the general result follows from this and the monotone convergence theorem (applied to $f_n(x)=f(nx),x \geq 0$).

How to relate $E[h|\mathcal{F}_n](x)$ (for a convenient $h$) to $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(y)dy$?

Comment: the given inequality can be rewritten as $\|\mathrm{E}[f|[0,x]]\|_p\leqslant \frac{p}{p-1}\|f\|_p$, however I dont see any filtration for this inequality

Comment: Why should this well written question showing personal work be closed ?

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer? Are you sure that there is such a proof? I ask b/c I remember when I first learned about the Doob $L^p$ max inequality, my professor brought up Hardy's ineq. as it also has the $(\frac p{p-1})^p$ factor, but looking at that prof's recent https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~radamcz/hdp/JonWellnerSlides.pdf (pg. 19, Open Questions, "Is there a simpler approach to ... Hardy’s two inequalities via probability theory?"), it seems like perhaps there is no (known) proof of Hardy using Doob? The associated paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11818.pdf also doesn't use Doob.

Comment: There is a proof, check page 74 3.15 https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-06400-9

Comment: Unfortunaly I did solve that one (noticed the exercise later, after months)

Comment: Check also 26 https://dornsife.usc.edu/sergey-lototsky/wp-content/uploads/sites/211/2023/06/Math507b-Sp2021.pdf

Comment: Therefore there is definetely a proof and for various version of Hardy inequality